# Marking and finding locations of elements of array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, find

I have a matrix having values between [0,1]. I want to find and mark the locations of those elements which have values <0.1 and >0.9.

So I use the matlab function **find**; but it returns me two vectors: a row and column vector distinctly which is difficult for analysis. So is there a way by which I can see the location of which elements meet the conditions without losing the original matrix structure?

I used the below line of code:

```
[r,c,v]= find(X<0.1 | X>0.9);    % X is my 512*512 matrix of values
```

Thanks!

Comment: How would you like to see the output? In a cell array maybe? Just the matching indices? It's still vague to me.

Comment: A cell array will be better with the matching indices. Basically,the logic is to find the locations of the matching values and then change the values at those specific locations for later analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works out for you -

```
%// cell array with each cell housing the  matching indices for each row
out = cellfun(@find,mat2cell(X<0.1 | X>0.9,ones(1,size(X,1)),size(X,2)),'uni',0)
```

Browse through the values of `out` using - `celldisp(out)`

Comment: yes...this works well...it gives me the individual columns where the matching occurs for each row! Great work!! Thanks @Divakar

Comment: @KashifNawaz Awesome! You know you can upvote answers too, not just this one, but others too that are useful to you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just by using condition like this :

```
mask = (X < 0.1 | X > 0.9)
```

Will return an array logical with 1 where condition is respected.

Comment: wow!! this is a really good solution also!! It preserves the inherent nature of the input matrix.  Going further on, I think the logical 1s can be read out with the array indices for further manipulation. Thanks @Alexandre Bizeau :)